# signals and slots in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I was going through this Qt tutorial where I came across a pretty interesting line of code

```
connect(slider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),this,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)));
```

Generally when a signal is emitted, then a slot is called. What is meant by this statement?
the "slider" is a QSlider object pointer.

If helpful, this is the [tutorial](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.3/tutorial-t8-lcdrange-cpp.html)  .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This statement tells the qt signal/slot mechanism to connect two signals, making the second being emitted if the first one is emitted. Look at documentation of QObject::connect it has an example where a signal from a private member variable is made available by connecting it to a public signal of the owner class, but i guess that is just one use case.

Comment: But when the second signal is emitted, which slot is executed?

Comment: Unless you connect something to it, nothing will be called. You have to connect the needed slot to the signal you connected the first one to.